# Beautiful Soup:Scrape Table Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm looking to extract table data from the url below.  Specifically I would like to extract the data in first column.  When I run the code below, the data in the first column repeats multiple times.   How can I get the values to show only once as it appears in the table?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'giftList'})

rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')
    for cell in data:
        print(data[0].text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'giftList'})

rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    data = row.find_all('td')

    if (len(data) > 0):
        cell = data[0]
        print(cell.text)
```

Comment: How do I extract data from only the first column?

Comment: @Zach You want to print the first column of each row?

Comment: @ Ozzy. Yes.  I only want the first column from the data.

Comment: @Zach I have edited the code. Does this do what you need? Please accept the answer if it does.

Comment: Perfect!   Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `requests` module in combination with `selectors` you can try like the following as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'lxml')
for table in soup.select('table#giftList tr')[1:]:
    cell = table.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True)
    print(cell)
```

Output:

```
Vegetable Basket
Russian Nesting Dolls
Fish Painting
Dead Parrot
Mystery Box
```